# Zero division error in python function even after using if-statement to avoid division by 0

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, divide-by-zero

I am writing a function that returns the total count of digits(of an integer) that can divide the integer that it is a part of.
For ex- Integer -111
        count - 3 as all 1,1,1 divide 111
        Integer - 103456
        count - 2 only divisible by 1,4.
To handle the special case of division by 0 , I have used if-else statements .However, I am still getting a zero divison error. Why am I still getting this error?
My error message:-ZeroDivisionError:`integer division or modulo by zero`

My code-

```
    count=0
    divisors_list=[]
    number_in_string = str(n)
    divisors_list=list(number_in_string)
    for divisor in divisors_list:
       if divisor != 0:
            if n%int(divisor) == 0:
               count+=1
    return count

x=findDigits(103456)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is bad usage of strings as integers.

One way to fix your code is:

```
def findDigits(n):
    count = 0
    number_in_string = str(n)
    divisors_list = list(number_in_string)
    for divisor in divisors_list:
        # *** at this point, divisor is a string ***
        divisor = int(divisor)  # <== cast it to int
        if divisor != 0:
            if n % divisor == 0:
               count += 1
    return count
```

Answer (score 1):

`int(divisor)` can be `0` even if `divisor != 0`.

```
>>> divisor = 0.5
>>> int(divisor)
0
```

I would suggest to ask for forgiveness instead of permission and just catch the `ZeroDivisionError`.

```
try:
    if n%int(divisor) == 0:
        count += 1
except ZeroDivisionError:
    pass
```

Comment: Or  a string : `”0”`.